# Overscroll ListView. Pull to refresh

Tags: android, listview, refresh, pull

I've implemented a pull to refresh in my app. I think it is right:

```
swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
        swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        swipeLayout.animate();
        swipeLayout.setColorSchemeResources(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright,
                android.R.color.holo_green_light,
                android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
                android.R.color.holo_red_light);

 public void onRefresh() {

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        }, 5000);
    }


    boolean canChildScrollUp()
    {
        return resultado.getFirstVisiblePosition()!=0;
    }
```

No errors and I think it's working fine. The problem is that I want to put an overscroll on the listview, not the message "Swipe to refresh", just the overscroll and I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: Look here may be this will help you  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583484/how-to-implement-android-pull-to-refresh

Comment: Thanks, actually my code works and refresh the content of the view, however, the thing that isn't in google documentation is the overscroll in the listview. Apps like Twitter or Facebook do that.

Comment: Can you post an image of that overscroll you are talking about for more details ?

Comment: Of course. I don't know how to attach an image here, I let you the link: http://cyrilmottier.com/media/2012/03/the-pull-to-refresh-an-anti-ui-pattern-on-android/pull_to_refresh.jpg

I mean the "white" space between the bar and the layout with the text, the space that says="Pull to refresh"...

Comment: I dont know how to that, but in listView you can add header to it an there put what you want and while the listView scrolling down you can change the layout to another.

Comment: Simple search on google gave the following links : [this](https://github.com/Larphoid/android-Overscroll-ListView), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803195/how-to-use-overscro) & [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19334323/how-to-detect-overscroll-in-android) & [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423912/listview-overscroll)

Comment: Thank you. I'll try some of this and let see